# Improving Server Response Time in a Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, devops, digital-ocean

I have developed a Laravel application where I submit an array with base64 data as a payload. In the backend, I don't interact with the request directly; I simply return a response. However, I've noticed a significant delay when submitting the form in the production environment, and this delay seems to be correlated with the length of the array. Surprisingly, when I submit the same payload in my local development environment, I receive an instant response. Is there a way to configure the server to achieve the same level of responsiveness as in the local environment?

Local Environment
[image: Local Environment]

Production Environment
[image: Production Environment]

I tried to do a live migration of Hypervisor in Digital Ocean to improve the performance, but the issue still persisted.

Comment: How big is your file? In localhost file is instantly used, but on production site, you have to wait file to upload, and that depends on file size and internet speed

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading 5 files. Your server and response has to wait for the upload to finish. This will depend on the size of the files and the connection speed.

In localhost the file is just being copied, which is much faster.

What you can do is implement some ajax chunk upload that can upload the files just as you select them and show some progress bar, before you pres the submit button.

Comment: Yes a know that files are just being copied, but I have this issue also if I convert files to base64, which are like array in javascript before submit with ajax form, so the issue that I am trying to solve is how to send an array of base64 in request without delay, I am looking for somehow to simulate production host as my localhost. This solution is more part of server http protocol and config than Laravel App.

Comment: converting the file to base64 will increase the size by ~25%, making your upload slower. The solution I gave was to start the upload before clicking submit, which can shave a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems may occur depending on the size/type of data in relation with the parameters below.

Please provide more info:

- http method
- Are you sending the payload as file (multipart) or post body?
- What is the size of the data uploaded?

Run `phpinfo()` in both environments and post the results for the following parameters

```ini
; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time = 60

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 30

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 32M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Also as already noted by kris localhost is literally the same machine so data upload is near instant, since all of network lag is omitted.